# On back button (browser) show json code

Tags: html, json, back-button

Don't know why, but on several my website pages when i click a back (only on back action) button on the browser it returns a window with JSON code, containing data.

What could be the problem? Any solutions?
Website created with MVC4 and Jquery AJAX used to display lists of data. 
If needed i can post some code.

Edit: after refreshing the page everything is shown as it should.

Comment: On back button click, browser shows up the cached files, so when you refresh, browser send a new request and the page is rendered as desired.

Comment: Ok. I think i got it and i think a found an answer how is it possible to fix it. Thanks for info. Edit: Don't find a button to mark an answer :o